# Handling last line in Python CSV file reading

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm currently working on a project for my company. My first task is a relatively simple algorithm for reading a CSV file, formatting it correctly, then outputting it into a CSV  file. I am using Python 2.7

The simple way I have it set now outputs the data formatted in only one line as:

```
'item1','item2','item3','LAST_ITEM',
```

Desired output in one line is:

```
'item1','item2','item3','LAST_ITEM'
```

Essentially, I don't want the last comma to be present in the very last item in the list. Here is my simple code:

```
csvfile = csv.DictReader('csvfile.csv', delimiter=',')
outputFile = open('outputfile.txt')

for row_index, row in enumerate(csvfile):
  outputFile.write("'" + row['location'] + "',")
```

I know that there must be a way that I can check to see if the reader is at the last line so I can simply print a line excluding the last comma. So, I've been reading up a lot about generators and googling a lot of answers. Still, I can't quite put my finger on how to do this.

Comment: Any reason you're trying to use `csv.DictReader` on input but not the equivalent on output? Also - be handy to see what `isLast` is meant to be - to answer your question the community will need more - you also be confusing rows (potentially lines) and columns... which is it?

Comment: My apologies!! I've been experimenting around with different options and it's meant to be just enumerate(csvfile). It was just copy/pasted incorrectly.

Comment: Additionally, I'm just using the print function here instead of file.write() as a way to quickly test the output without having to write to a file each time.

Comment: You need to additionally add desired input/output - you're encountering a problem (I think) that wouldn't be a problem if you weren't trying to test it in the wrong way :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added the desired output now. This is my first time asking questions here so thank you for the advice.

Comment: Look at `csv.DictWriter` ?

Comment: I was under the impression `csv.DictWriter` writes each element as a row and not as one line. I have specified I want to consolidate each element in only one line.

Comment: Not to my reading... say you have a CSV file with a million rows, did you want a million columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A million columns with only one row.

Comment: Do-able - but **why**? ie - you'd have to duplicate the columns heads n many times across all the what use to row column headers... it'd just be one line of stuff that very little software would be capable of loading

Comment: Frankly, because I'm an intern and this is the task that was given to me. I didn't ask too many questions : ). Additionally, there's lots of data but only about 10,000 rows in the original csv file anyway. So, not millions. I'm not sure if that makes a difference in what you mean.

Comment: You're supposed to ask those that assign the task what you don't understand rather than strangers that take their time to try to pull details out from you :p

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to extract the values from one column of the input CSV file and output those values to a CSV file in a single row?

You can use `join()` to do this in one go:

```
import csv

with open('csvfile.csv') as infile, open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(','.join("'{}'".format(row['location']) for row in csv.DictReader(infile)))
    outfile.write("\n")
```

Or you could use `csv.writer` to output to the CSV file:

```
import csv

with open('csvfile.csv') as infile, open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
    out_csv.writerow(["'{}'".format(row['location']) for row in csv.DictReader(infile)])
```

Comment: thank you! Although the output was very close to what I wanted it was still missing the single quotes. All I did was rewrite the last line as `outfile.write(','.join("'"+row['location']+"'" for row in csv.DictReader(infile)))` and it worked!

Comment: @repr0: oh yes, I missed the quotes. I fixed the answer to now use `"'{}'".format()` which I think is better than string concatenation.